# How to retrieve values from a google spreadsheet to a textfield using HtmlService

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a web application using HTML Service and want the user to be able to load data that is saved in the spreadsheet.

I have successfully done it using a scriptlet when the page loads, but can't do it on the click of a button.

Here is my .gs :

```
function getData() {
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/xxxx").getSheetByName("xxx"),
  rng = ss2.getRange(1,1,ss2.getLastRow(),8),
  data = rng.getValues();
  Logger.log(data[0][0]);
  return (data[0][0]);
}
```

And here is the .html :

The trigger :

```
<input type="button" id="load" value="load" onclick="getform()" />
```

The script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getform() {
    var data = google.script.run.getData();
    $('#xxxx').text(data);
    alert(data);
  }
</script>
```

The log shows the correct data but the the alert returns "undefined". I'm really at a loss here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google.script.run is asynchronous and you need to have a callback function that will run when the server returns the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getform() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData();
 }

 function onSuccess(data) {
    $('#xxxx').text(data);
    alert(data);
 }
</script>
```